# episode file for maven-jaxb22-plugin

Tags: maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb-episode

I have a schema `A.xsd` that imports `B.xsd` and its one of the complex element `<complex-element>`. Now I have created the `.episode` file from compiling the `B.xsd` and used as input to `A.xsd`. But except for the `<complex-element>`, all other child elements classes are regenerated again.

**A.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/a" xmlns="http://example.com/a"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/b" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/b" schemaLocation="b.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <!-- more elements -->
                <xs:element name="elementx" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element ref="tns:complex-element" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**B.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/b" xmlns="http://example.com/b"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="complex-element">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="list" type="list" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="code" type="code" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="list">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="file" type="file" minOccurs="1"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="code">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="S1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="S2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="S3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
<!-- more elements -->
</xs:schema>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<execution>
    <id>aschema</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>a.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <bindingIncludes>
            <include>a.xjb</include>
        </bindingIncludes>
        <cleanPackageDirectories>false</cleanPackageDirectories>
        <episode>false</episode>
        <args>
            <arg>-b</arg>
            <arg>${basedir}/src/main/resources/b-episode</arg>
            <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
            <arg>-Xxew</arg>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
        </args>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

After execution, the Class `ComplexElement` gets correctly referenced to existing package, but all of the child elements `<list>` and `<code>` generates class under the package of `org.example.com.a` instead to refer existing classes inside `org.example.com.b` package.

**b-episode**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" if-exists="true"
    version="2.1">
    <bindings xmlns:tns="http://example.com/b"
        if-exists="true" scd="x-schema::tns">
        <schemaBindings map="false">
            <package name="org.example.com.b" />
        </schemaBindings>
        <bindings if-exists="true" scd="tns:complex-element">
            <class ref="org.example.com.b.ComplexElement" />
        </bindings>
        <bindings if-exists="true" scd="~tns:list">
            <class ref="org.example.com.b.List" />
        </bindings>
        <bindings if-exists="true" scd="~tns:file">
            <class ref="org.example.com.b.File" />
        </bindings>
        <!-- and so on ... -->
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the documentation on [using episodes](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes).

In short, instead of using the `.episode` file as a file, include the compiled artifact of the schema `A.xsd` as an `episodes/episode` in the plugin configuration:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>a-schema</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <episodes>
                    <episode>
                        <groupId>com.acme.foo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>a-schema</artifactId>
                        <!-- Version is not required if the artifact is
                            configured as dependency -->
                    </episode>
                </episodes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So you shouldn't `-b ${basedir}/src/main/resources/b-episode` etc.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Comment: Thanks I did see the link. But I cant, because both of schema are part of same pom.xml and in different execution phases.

Comment: why cannot it work like `-b ${basedir}/src/main/resources/b-episode`  this way? Its flexible to use episode file output from previous execution. Infact I have used  `<arg>` for one of the project that has `xsd:simpletype` and it worked. This time though the `xs:complex-type` child elements is regenerated.

Comment: @ulab I'd recommend separating them in different Maven modules then. It can work with `-b ${basedir}/src/main/resources/b-episode` but you better use `bindingDirectory` and `bindingIncludes` instead of `-b`. The reason that it does not work for you is probably that you have `*.episode` file and do `-b` to a directory. XJC searches for `**/*.xjb` then. If you use condiguration elements at least you could do `mvn clean install -X` and we could check the log. With `-b` you're on your own.